# How to separate (new,create,delete) actions and show action in Rails for a blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to build a blog and having some issues. The blog have a separate dashboard with its own layout `/dashboard`. Imagine that I have a model named post. In the blog, the blog post URLs will be like `/post/hello-world`. Normally its easy to add, edit and delete these posts. I just have to add `resources :posts` in the routes and edit like `/post/new`.

But I need to move the new, create and destroy actions to the dashboard. So it will be like `dashboard/post/new`. I tried to do this by adding the new action in dash controller and trying to post to `post` create action. It failed. Tried to change only the path for create (post) and new actions and it also failed.

My question is, in a situation like this, what is the standard way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:only/:except` options in the routes

```
resources :posts, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]
scope 'dashboard' do
  resources :posts, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
```

Output of rake routes

```
      posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
  edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
       post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
            PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
            POST   /dashboard/posts(.:format)     posts#create
   new_post GET    /dashboard/posts/new(.:format) posts#new
            DELETE /dashboard/posts/:id(.:format) posts#destroy
```

Note: If you want a separate controller for for dashboard, you can use `namespace 'dashboard'` instead of `scope`

Comment: I already have a dahsboard controller. So, my routes will be like this `get 'dashboard', to: 'dash#show'`, `resources :posts, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]`, `namespace 'dashboard' do`, `resources :posts, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]`, `end` right?  Please correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend to set dashboard layout in post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 layout "dashboard"

 def create
  # your code for create
 end

end
```